# LWUIT black lines between components

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have next question regarding LWUIT:

I have container with child components. A black lines around the child components shown on the screen, how can I remove them?

I tried to install zero option to padding and margin, but it did'nt help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the border style for that child component. And if you using border means set the border to `null` or create the empty border for that child component.

**Note:** Ask the question clearly. Because you said child component, But you didn't mention which component you are using as a child component.